# Hosting ASP.NET on Azure for a GoDaddy Domain using CNAME

Tags: domains, godaddy, asp.net, cname, azure

Since GoDaddy [does not support ASP.NET Core](https://www.godaddy.com/pro/plesk-hosting) (and probably won't for a long time since they are still on old ASP.NET 4.5 now) I would like to host my website on Azure. According to [this document](https://azure.microsoft.com/de-de/documentation/articles/web-sites-godaddy-custom-domain-name/) this is possible using CNAME.

Will it be possible to create a CNAME for the rootdomain (e.g. mydomain.com)? I have read several times there could be problems.

Also: How does this work with Email? The Product "GoDaddy Domain" supports free unlimited email forwading will this still work?

Is there anything else I need to watch out for?

If CNAME is not the "correct" approach, what would be a better way to host a website of a domain from godaddy somewhere else?

Comment: You just need to add your A record and point it to Azure IP address in order to host your ASP.NET Core site.

Comment: But IP-addresses may change on Azure. I'd have to update that record manually whenever the IP addressed changed?

Comment: Yes, you need to change the IP manually on Godaddy control panel.

Comment: I am sure no one wants to update ip-addresses manually. Isn't there an automatic solution to this general problem?

Comment: Use the instructions for A records rather than CNAME records: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-domain#create-the-a-record  Azure has some work around where you use a TXT record with your app name to tell the static server at the A record which app to route the domain to.

Comment: In that doc it days "*App Service uses this record only at configuration time, to verify that you own the custom domain. After your custom domain is validated and configured in App Service, you can delete this TXT record.*" So I should keep that TXT record anyway and it will use it if the IP-address changes?

Answer (score 2):

The DNS standard does not support using CNAME records for the zone apex (root domain), some DNS providers get around this by creating a virtual CNAME record where you add where it should reference and the DNS server checks the IP address of the CNAME resolution and sends that back at the time of the query. As for your email question you can use any provider for emails and so can continue using the GoDaddy email forwarding service while hosting the site with a different provider.

Comment: That sounds like it is not a good idea to use CNAME for what I want to do. What would be a better approach? The GoDaddy Zone-File allows me to to the following entries: **A (Host),AAAA (IPv6-Host),CNAME (Alias),MX (Mail Exchanger),TXT (Text),SRV (Service),NS (Nameserver)**

Comment: One option would be to change your DNS host to one that supports the concept of DNAME which is in effect a dynamic A record which has only recently started being used for larger DNS hosting providers such as Amazon Web Services' Route 53 product. The issue with this is that in effect it is a work around to bypass the DNS standards and isn't very reliable yet. A better option would be to CNAME www.domain.com and point the zone apex to an existing server and send a 302 Redirect header to the www.domain.com CNAME record.

Comment: That would result in all users always seeing the www subdomain in their browsers, right? I'd like to avoid that. It seems that the A record is my only choice. Now I just need to get notified somehow, when azure changes the IP-address of my webapp so I can update that entry.